# Additional Quick step Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: windows, macos, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

Use a lot of keyboard shortcuts through Quick step actions. This lets me sort incoming mail into folders pretty quickly. Limit of course is I can only assign 9 of them. Which is a little limiting.

You'll also ask why? I use a Stream Deck. So I can assign any hotkey action and then name it. This leads to a pretty helpful list of actions. I'd like to add more of them.

[image: Image of Stream Deck Outlook]

I assume the answer is likely to be macros but if it is, is there any tutorial you could link me to.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Outlook client, i'm afraid that only nine keyboard shortcuts are available and there's no option to add the number of them. It's by design.